# How do I randomize an object's position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

This is some code that instantiates prefabs of two different types and places them in a random spot. The prefabs instantiate, but don't instantiate randomly. How can I fix this???

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {
// Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating ("SpawnAThing", 3.0f, 3.0f);
    }

// Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    void SpawnAThing(){
        GameObject x=null;
        int z = Random.Range (0, 2);
        switch (z) {
        case 0:
            x = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("BadCircle"));;
            break;
        case 1:
            x = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("GoodCircle"));
            break;
        }
        x.transform.position.Set (Random.Range (-Screen.width, Screen.width), Random.Range (-Screen.height, Screen.height), 0.0f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not working properly due to the use of `transform.position.Set()`

`position.Set()` cannot modify the position because it does not return the reference of that position. It returns a copy.

Modify the transform directly with `x.transform.position = new Vector3(x,y,z);`

So all you have to do is replace

```
x.transform.position.Set (Random.Range (-Screen.width, Screen.width), Random.Range (-Screen.height, Screen.height), 0.0f);
```

with

```
x.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-Screen.width, Screen.width), Random.Range(-Screen.height, Screen.height), 0.0f);
```

**EDIT**:

You can't see it now because `Screen.width` and `Screen.height` are way too off to the screen. You have to convert **view** to **world** point with `Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint` then you can use **0** to **1** to represent the screen with **.5** being the middle point.
If you don't see it, decrease 15 that is passed into the Z-axis.

```
  x.transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), Camera.main.nearClipPlane + 15f));
```

Comment: @VolcanicTitan It doesn't work at all because this is the right  to change the transform. The reason you don't see the object is because Your random number is out of the view/screen. You can prove this by running the program, selecting one the instantiated object, go to Scene View and press F. You will find it in another random place. Your positions are off the screen. Is this a 3D or 2D object?

Comment: Having never used unity - which means I may be way off base - but a random number between -width and +width seems like it would be off screen half the time. Couple that with the height, and it would be off-screen 3/4 of the time. Should it not be `(0,width)` and similarly, `(0, height)`? I realise this was the original definition provided by the OP, but perhaps this is the cause of the non-working code for this solution.

Comment: @Rob Yes you are correct. The thing is off the screen. Not just because of `-` he used but also because of the values he used. I tried `(0,width)` and it was still off the screen. In Unity, you convert view to world point then you can use 0 to 1 value to present the screen. `.5` is the middle point. Take a look at my edit to see what I am saying.

Comment: @VolcanicTitan Answer is modified so that you can actually see the object.

Answer (score 0):

Create a GameObject and rename it to "SpawnController" and attach this script:

```
 using UnityEngine;

    public class SpawnController : MonoBehaviour {

        //Set at inspector new Min and Max X axis Range.
        public float maxWidth;
        public float minWidth;

        //Set at inspector new Min and Max Y axis Range
        public float maxHeight;
        public float minHeight;

        //Set at inspector new Min and Max Z axis Range (3D game)
        public float maxDepth;
        public float minDepth;

        //Set the time at inspector you want the object to be created eg: every 10 seconds
        public float rateSpawn;

        private float currentRateSpawn;

        // Drag to inspector your gameObject what you want instatiate
        public GameObject gameObject;

        void Update () {

            currentRateSpawn += Time.deltaTime;
            if (currentRateSpawn > rateSpawn) {
                currentRateSpawn = 0;
                Spawn ();
            }
        }

        private void Spawn() {


            //Define new (Min and Max) range values for the Vector3 AXIS
            float randWitdh = Random.Range(minWidth, maxWidth);
            float randHeight = Random.Range(minHeight, maxHeight);
            float randDepth = Random.Range(minDepth, maxDepth);

            //Vector3 now has a new random range value
            Vector3 random =  new Vector3(randWitdh, randHeight, randDepth ); 

            //Object will dynamically instantiate according to the values established in the inspector
            Instantiate (gameObject, random, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
```